# Magento 2 Product Salable Quantity shows 0 even if Qty is greater than 0

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, quantity, swatches

The products **Salable Quantity** of Simple products shows **zero(0)**. But its **Quantity** is **greater than zero (>0)**.
Due to this product swatches are not showing correctly on the front end.

Magento admin grid showing Product **Qty: 1** and **Salable Quantity: 0**
[image]

Frontend Showing size available but when selected and click on Add to Cart button. Then shows an error message of quantity not available.
[image]

Can anyone please suggest to me here why my store product's **Salable Quantity** shows **zero(0)**?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link:

https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-salable-quantity-vs-quantity/

And in short:

Saleable qty is introduced in magento 2.3 with MSI.

Saleable qty is available qty for sell, ordered qty saved in reservation table.

For more info:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/reservations.html

And **for disable-stock-reservation** you can use **`Ampersand_DisableStockReservation`** module:

https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation

I hope it will help you